# How to get folder information from dropbox with vue

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, dropbox

I have a vue application where I want to fetch every information of my account with the filesListFolder method but I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Illegal invocation
    at eval
```

Could someone explain to me what is wrong with my code? I did not really understand the error message. I have not selected the app folder option in dropbox generating my app but the full dropbox one.

Here is my code:

```
getImages() {
      require("isomorphic-fetch");
      const Dropbox = require("dropbox").Dropbox;
      const dbx = new Dropbox({
        accessToken: 'AcessToken',
        fetch
      });
      dbx.filesListFolder({ path: '' })
          .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response.entries);
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
            console.error(error);
          });
    },
  }
```

Comment: Are you trying to call `getImages` on the client/ in a vuejs app? This looks like code that belongs to a nodejs server, not a vuejs app. If so, why are you requiring `isomorphic-fetch` which is supposed to use on the backend?

Comment: This is called in the frontend side. This was shown in the instalation guide the isomorphic fetch part thats why it is there but I do not use it

Comment: require is not used on the frontend, that's node 90% of the cases unless you have something specific going on there. Also, could you link the documentation that you are using to do this? Maybe I can give you a  hand on how to do it.